# Need Debian 3.1 full iso

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, debian-based

Can anyone tell me where I can get the FULL CD/DVD iso for Debian 3.1r4? It is not at Debian's website. The website only has other versions which are not what I need.
Alternatively, is there a version of Ubuntu that is based on Debian 3.1r4?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you *specifically* need that exact version? Your question is off-topic, but perhaps if explaining your *exact* reason you might get some on-topic help. So please edit your question, and show the relevance to some source code of yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from archive e.g. [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/3.1_r4/). But really, why do you need such an old and unsupported version? It's been about 10 years since release.

Comment: These are not the full iso's. They are the netinst and businesscard versions, which is not what I need. I am using Debian 3.1r4 as part of some training material that calls for it specifically.

Comment: You can rebuild the iso by using jigdo.

Comment: @thechico seems like quite obsolete training material... Lots of methods common for this ancient version are now deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that using jigdo was the best option. I thought it wasn't working because I had screenfulls of 404 messages. However, after letting it run for over an hour, I had the full isos.
Appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: The main point is still that you will be using a massively obsolete, massively insecure platform.